# SAS Teradata ODBC timestamp

Tags: sas, timestamp, odbc, teradata

I'm trying to make my SAS Teradata query a little more efficient.
I can get the where timestamp filter in the outer nest to work but it doesnt work when i try to place it in the inner nest.  I know i'm overlooking something really simple.  Thanks for the help!

```
SELECT  *
FROM    CONNECTION TO ODBC                                       
       (
        SELECT   name, ID, timestamp

        FROM    TD.table
        WHERE   
        timestamp > 1764460800
        )
/*          where timestamp > 1764460800 */
/*outside nest*/
;
quit;
```

1764460800 = 11/30/2015

Comment: Not seeing a question here...

Comment: sorry .. got trigger happy and forgot the question wasn't actually asked. I updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using pass through, you need to 'pass through' valid syntax for the underlying database.  In this case you are looking for:

```
proc sql;
SELECT  *
FROM    CONNECTION TO ODBC                                       
       (
        SELECT   name, ID, timestamp

        FROM    TD.table
        WHERE   
        timestamp > date '2015-11-30' /* Teradata format */
        )
        where timestamp > 1764460800  /* SAS format */
;
quit;
```